# Backup and restore procedure

Tags: mysql

I am having only MYI files is it possible to restore my database with this files.?

If yes means tell me the procedure please

Comment: With the `engine` MyISAM you need `.frm` as well as `.myd` files

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible
 You will need the `MYD` file.
 The `MYI` file only stores the indexes and does not contain any data.

Answer (score 0):

`MyISAM` table uses three files: a format file that stores the definition of the table structure, a data file that stores the contents of table rows, and an index file that stores any indexes on the table.

These files are distinguished from one another by their suffixes. For example, the format, data, and index files for a table named mytable are called `mytable.frm`, `mytable.MYD`, and `mytable.MYI`. MySQL normally stores all three files in the database directory for the database that contains the table.

You have to take a backup using [MySQLhotbackup](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlhotcopy.html) and [Percona XtraBackup](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/)